# Where does BasiEgaXorz write its compiled Sega Genesis binary (basic.bin) to?

Tags: basic, device-emulation

BasiEgaXorz is an old Win32 program that allows you to write BASIC programs and compile them to Sega Genesis cartridge or Sega CD ROMs.

I get this screen:

[image]

But where is my ROM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the installed version on Windows 10, `basic.bin` is written to `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\basiegaxorz\basic.bin`.

`basic.bin` can be used with any Genesis emulator, and used on a real Genesis.

[image]

For some reason, this path cannot be changed in the Options, and is not listed anywhere in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is correct if you're running BEX out of the Program Files folder only, unless you have UAC turned off.

If you run it from a different folder structure (like C:\Bex), the output will be in C:\Bex (or wherever the compiler is). If you save the source, you can also output to your projects folder.

BEX was written for XP era version of Windows and doesn't take into account for UAC from Win7 onward.